# Firefox + flash player + adblock plus on Youtube: video freezes

Tags: 16.04, firefox, youtube, firefox-extensions, adblock

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04.

Firefox + flash player + adblock plus on Youtube: why do videos freeze after about 1 minute?

If I reload the page, the video suddenly runs fine.

(I suspect Youtube's nasty trick against adblockers).

Anyone can confirm this issue?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using the Flash YouTube player? The HTML5 player is much better for multiple reasons

Comment: @AndroidDev HTML5 used to make CPU run high.

Answer (score 0):

Something that may fix this is to update your AdBlockPlus fliters, often when AdBlockPlus filters are old you may have problems with advertising like Youtube has, causing problems.  You can on some older versions of ABP update all filters at once, on newer versions you have to update each subscription.

I only have the newer version available at the moment, you click on the little down arrow by the adblock plus icon, then "filter preferences", then in the section "filter selections", click on each "action button", then select "update filters".  You have to do each filter individually in the ABP version I have on this computer, older versions have an update filters in the filter preferences which does the whole mess at once(In my opinion they should have left it the old way but...).  Anyway filters get updated more often then the addin, so when you have a bug show up on a site with advertisements, then updating the filters will often fix it.  I generally only update filters when I see a problem on a site with advertising.

In general you will find Flash is going away.  Youtube does not need it anymore.  I use an addin called "quickjava" that has buttons to enable disable a bunch of settings.  I normally turn off "flash", "Java", "silverlight" and only enable them if I view a page that I feel is safe that needs them.  It makes your browser much more secure(Most web virus, trojans, etc. use flash or java to run, sometimes javascript but not as much as the other two.).  I usually leave javascript on as a great many web sites use it, but I turn it off if going to a page I'm unsure of(Links given to me by shall we say humorous friends, being one an example of sites to turn off javascript on.).